# Chances of hitting a deer depending on the vehicle's speed

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

My friend and I are arguing about the following hypothetical scenario.

**Context**

There is a stretch of road of let's say 100km. This road is prone to having deers crossing it. You drive a motorbike through the road.

**Scenario 1**
Your speed is 100km/h (60mph)

**Scenario 2**
Your speed is 200km/h (124mph)

**Question 1 :** In which of these scenarios are you more likely to see a deer (being in the same general area as the deer.

**Question 2 :** In which of these scenarios are you more likely to hit a deer (being at the exact same spot as the deer). He also compared the situation with looking at a part of the sky to see shooting stars. By spending more time looking at the spot in the sky you increase your chance

**My hypothesis** is that the speed doesn't affect your chances at either scenario.

**My friend's hypothesis** is that it is Scenario 1 that increases your chances of seeing/hitting a deer for the simple reason that you spend more time in the "risk" zone

Thank you for your help

Comment: This is a dangerous argument for car drivers to accelerate through crossroads/intersections - to reduce the time spent passing the length of their car through potential collision points

Comment: I live in an area where deer wander in unpredictable patterns. The speed limit is 35mph and needs to be. Deer show no signs of evolving to be wary of traffic. Drivers show no signs of evolving to expect deer.

Answer (score 0):

The risk of hitting the deer is harder to pin down, since you will have less reaction time at the higher speed. However, your friend is right about seeing deer. (It isn't clear that you are allowing the car to brake to try to stop short of a deer, however.)

Let's say that there is a chance of deer wandering through in a given minute of $p>0$. This means that the probability of no deer wandering through in $m$ minutes is $(1-p)^m$. The larger the $m$, the smaller the probability of seeing no deer. The way you get a larger $m$ is by spending more time on the road, so driving slower.

This assumes independence, which I find unrealistic, but it gets at the point. (It also assumes that something like the sound of a fast car does not scare away the deer.)